# Finding the index number of the lowest value in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to return the index number of the lowest value in an array of 12 numbers. I keep getting 12 as the result every time I run it. Here is my code:

```
minRain = leastRain(months);

public static int leastRain (double[] mon4){
    int lowest = (int) mon4[0];

    for (int index=1; index<mon4.length; index++){
        if (mon4[index]<lowest)
            lowest = index;
    }
    return lowest;  
}

System.out.println("The month with the lowest amount of rain is: " + (minRain + 1));
```

Comment: hmm while I could provide an answer I'm pretty sure we have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, can you edit the question and tell us the "X" :) ?

Comment: You are setting `lowest` to the lowest value initially and then setting it to the index value in the loop.  You need to track the index and value separately.

Answer (score 3):

It is a silly mistake you made - you assigned index to your variable instead of an array value. Do this:

```
public static int leastRain (double[] mon4){
    int lowest = 0;

    for (int index=1; index<mon4.length; index++){
        if (mon4[index]<mon4[lowest])
            lowest = index;
    }
    return lowest;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning array value to the `lowest`, so change it as shown below:

```
public static int leastRain (double[] mon4){
    int lowestIndex = 0;//set index as 0 instead of array value
    int lowestValue = mon4[0];
    for (int index=1; index<mon4.length; index++){
        if (mon4[index] < lowestValue)
            lowestIndex = index;
    }
    return lowestIndex;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store lowest_seen and lowest_index. Right now you are comparing value < last_index

Answer (score 1):

What is the meaning of this statement?

```
int lowest = (int) mon4[0];
```

You are saving the first value of the array as the lowest one and then later comparing with array values. You are actually comparing index with array values.

```
if (mon4[index]<lowest) // comparing lowest as an array value
    lowest = index;     // saving the index as the lowest value
```

You should do something like this.

```
 if (mon4[index]<mon4[lowest]) // comparing value of 'index' 'vs. 'lowest' index location
     lowest = index;
```